# Is ReCAPTCHA v3 is safe for my site?

Tags: captcha

Do you recommend using `Google Recaptcha V3` or using `Custom Captcha`(like enter a number)?

[Some people say](https://www.fastcompany.com/90369697/googles-new-recaptcha-has-a-dark-side) that `Google Recaptcha V3` causes problems for the site, such as error (Creating insecurity on the site), is it true?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a security question but a compatibility question. "Errors" is not a security result.

Comment: "causes problems for the site, such as errors" -- what's the security angle for the question?>

Comment: ...and errors are bad, right?

Comment: If you don't explain what you mean, it's difficult to understand what you are asking. "Some people say" -- please provide a reference to people saying this.

Comment: That link says absolutely nothing about errors and an impact to your site.

Comment: If you cannot behave in a mature and professional way, then maybe this site is not for you. You asked an incomprehensible question, and when we asked clarifying questions, you got emotional. When asked for a link, the link had nothing to do with your question. We'd love to help, but we don't know what you are asking. And it doesn't help when you respond with swearing.